# How can we convert an array of Object to List in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Ex: `Object[] arrObject1 = new Object[]{true, true, false, true, false}`

```
Object[] arrObject2 = new Object[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

How can we convert `Object[]` to `List`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(array);`